# Failed at the sharp@0.18.2 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'

Tags: node.js, docker, ubuntu-16.04, sharp

Facing issue while build docker file.here is my docker file and local ubuntu machine it's working but with docker, i can build it successfully. the error throw from npm sharp all other module working fine.

```
npm ERR! 

Linux 4.4.0-83-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v7.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! sharp@0.18.2 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the sharp@0.18.2 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the sharp package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs sharp
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls sharp
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2017-08-18T07_20_00_066Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Did you check with the module owner on github?